# Problems with StackingRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn

this error occurred when I used scikit-learn to perform model fusion on 7 sub-models. I checked the official document and there was no relevant introduction.

```
code:
# model fusion
estimators = [('DT', model_dt_x), ('KNN', model_knn_x), ('SVR', model_svr_x), ('ANN', model_ann_x), ('RF', model_rf_x), ('GBDT', model_gbdt_x), ('XGBT', model_xgbt_x)]
stacking_regressor = StackingRegressor(estimators=estimators, final_estimator=RidgeCV())
stacking_regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "i:/Lab/20210xxx/ex.py", line 86, in <module>
stacking_regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_stacking.py", line 680, in fit
return super().fit(X, y, sample_weight)
File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_stacking.py", line 148, in fit
for est in all_estimators if est != 'drop'
File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 921, in __call__
if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 759, in dispatch_one_batch
self._dispatch(tasks)
File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 716, in _dispatch
job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 182, in 
apply_async
result = ImmediateResult(func)
File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 549, in __init__
self.results = batch()
File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 225, in __call__
for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 225, in <listcomp>
for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_base.py", line 40, in 
_fit_single_estimator
estimator.fit(X, y)
File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\_multilayer_perceptron.py", 
line 641, in fit
return self._fit(X, y, incremental=False)
File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\_multilayer_perceptron.py", 
line 321, in _fit
self._validate_hyperparameters()
File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\_multilayer_perceptron.py", 
line 385, in _validate_hyperparameters
if self.max_fun <= 0:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: Please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed) and it should not be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter (edited out).

Comment: Please ensure that *all* the models are indeed regression ones, and that you have not included any classifier in your stack - see how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I particularly want to add code, but too much code will cause the post to fail!

Comment: It's an issue with the neural network you have. Which is not exposed here...

Comment: When I get rid of the neural network model, and still report this error.

Comment: The error is probably different. But this is not reproducible,

Comment: I don't think so, It's the same error every time.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved

```
model_ann_x = MLPRegressor(**model_ann.get_params())
model_ann_x.set_params(max_fun=15000) # get rid of bug
model_rf_x = RandomForestRegressor(**model_rf.get_params())
model_rf_x.set_params(ccp_alpha=0.0) # get rid of bug
model_gbdt_x = GradientBoostingRegressor(**model_gbdt.get_params())
model_gbdt_x.set_params(ccp_alpha=0.0) # get rid of bug
```